# capture data in date format from textbox

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I have a form where in the user enters the Cheque Date as 22/11/2013 (dd-mm-yyyy)

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(txtChequeDated.Text); // Error here
frmChqDt = dt.ToString("DD/MM/YYYY");
```

Error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Please advice

Comment: Are you using Web form or windows form application?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify proper custom formats for both date and year

Custom formats:

> Date => dd
>    Month => MM
>   Year => yyyy

To Specify the exact format you can use TryParseExact:

Syntax: `DateTime.TryParseExact(date,format,IFormatProvider,DateTimeStyles,out dateparameter)`

Try this:

```
DateTime result;  
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(txtChequeDated.Text,"dd/MM/yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,out result))
{
  frmChqDt = result.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter : if you can not explain the problem in my answer then please retract your downvote. otherwise explain the mistake.

Comment: I can't accept this answer, I'm not the asker..Only the asker can accept an answer..

Comment: @User2012384 : :) sorry i did not check the OP's name :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to validate your input.

See [this function](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match) in c# to validate using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("22/11/2013","dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
```

By the way, just found an article about C# DateTime format:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/